# Parse list of files

Tags: git, bash, sh

Imagine that we are running simple `git diff --name-only`. Output will be like this:

```
/path1/path2/path3/path4/file1
/path1/path2/path3/path4/file2
/path1/path2/file3
/file4
/path1/file5
```

The goal is to have such function that will able to parse  and count any part within path. For example if I run:

```
// 1 -> is the column to watch/count.
// In example output above it is: path1, path1, path1, path4, path1
// For 2 -> path2, path2, path2, null, file5
// For 3 -> path3, path3, file3, null, null
git diff --name-only | someFn(1)
```

And it should output total number of different matches. 
For example:

```
1 -> should output 2 (path1, file4)
2 -> should output 3 (path2, null, file5)
3 -> should output 3 (path3, file3, null)
```

The output of the function should be a simple number `0, 1, 2..`

Who could help me with it?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of bash (`echo $BASH_VERSION`)?  I ask because this is an obvious use of associative arrays.   Those are in bash 4.0, otherwise we can use `awk`.

Comment: $BASH_VERSION is 3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: @hek2mgl I was trying to unsuccessfully use `grep -e`. And different combinations of `awk`.

Comment: Post your attempts here. Then we can give suggest improvements or suggest to use something else. That's the idea behind stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `awk` with specific field separator:

```
git diff --name-only | awk -F "/" '{ print $2 }'
```

will show

```
path1
path1
path1
file4
path1
```

The awk basically split the string on `/`

You can also count matches with awk, sort and uniq.

```
git diff --name-only | awk -F "/" '{ print $3 }' | awk 'NF' | sort -u | wc -l
>2
```

This will output third column, remove empty line, sort the result and remove duplicates and finally count the results.
A combination of those commands should solve your need.

Comment: `awk -F "/" '{ print $3 }' | awk 'NF'` can properly be: `awk -F "/" '$3 != "" { print $3 }'`. Also `sort` usually have `sort -u` which is the same as `sort | uniq`.

Comment: Good tips. I added your `sort -u` recommandation. However I feel that using awk a second time with only `NF` has the advantage that you don't need to specify the column "$3" two times. First in the condition to remove empty lines and then a second time to actually print it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function like:

```
function fun() { cut -d / -f $(($1+1)) | sort -u | wc -l ;}
```

And then:

```
for i in $(seq 6) ; do
  git diff --name-only | fun $i
done
```

`function` may be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Using GAWK:

```
$ git diff --name-only | awk -F "/" 'NF > 2 { a[$3]=1 }
                                     END    { print length(a) }'
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `cut`:

```
git diff --name-only | cut -d '/' -f2
```

Would give you

```
path1
path1
path1
file4
path1
```

to sort and count unique values (as previously said):

```
git diff --name-only | cut -d '/' -f2 | sort -u | wc -l
```

I suspect the solution with `cut` would run faster than `awk` for larger inputs.